# Chrome extension: is it possible to reconnect to an orphan tab with an injected script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that injects scripts into a page programmatically from a background script.

The extension is often restarted while a page continues to run with that injected script.

However, once the extension is restarted, the content script can no longer communicate with the background.

So, is it possible to reconnect to an orphan tab after extension is restarted, without having to inject another script onto that page?

Comment: No. The only way is to reinject the content script. Why is that a problem?

Comment: well, if you inject a script again, there will be two scripts running simultaneously, which is not good

Comment: That's gonna be a problem only if you have DOM event listeners, which you can solve by detecting the orphaned state using e.g. https://crbug.com/649947#c16 and if it's detected, manually detach the listeners.

Comment: I had dom event listener indeed, and I indeed solved it with try catch while trying to send the message, so if it fails I would disconnect the listener. But in my opinion this is a very filthy quirk.